# How to write trigger that Only administrators must be able to delete events and tasks with status = 'Completed' or 'Open'?

Tags: trigger

I have written the trigger. But i want to identify it's related to Opportunity.
Please help me out

Apex Trigger

```
trigger NoDeleteonTask on Task (before delete) {
   String strProfileId = UserInfo.getProfileId();  
   List<Profile> profiles=[select id from Profile where name='System Administrator' ];
    List<Task> lstTask =new List<Task>();

    for (Task taskObj : Trigger.old) {  

        if ( profileId ==profiles[0].id && (taskObj.Status=='Completed' || taskObj.Status=='Open')  ) {
            lstTask.add(taskObj);
        } else {
            a.addError('You can't delete this record');
        }
    }
        delete lstTask;
}
```

Comment: What does **"But i want to identify it's related to Opportunity."** means?

Comment: If the task record related to "Opportunity" Objcet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to delete the tasks a second time; they're already on their way to the recycle bin when this trigger executes.

For your main question, you can check the type of WhatId:

```
taskObj.WhatId != null && taskObj.WhatId.getSObjectType() == Opportunity.SObjectType
```

Your overall trigger could be written as follows:

```
trigger NoDeleteOnTask on Task (before delete) {
    if([Select Profile.Name FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()]
       .Profile.Name != 'System Administrator']) {
        for(Task record: Trigger.old) {
            if(record.WhatId != null &&
               (record.Status == 'Completed' || record.Status == 'Open') &&
               record.WhatId.getSObjectType() == Opportunity.SObjectType) {
                record.addError('Only admins can delete a task that is not open or completed for an opportunity.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have created one task in Opportunity and when i try to delete with different profile ,It's got deleted..Please guide me

Comment: @uma451 Did you delete the task or opportunity? What was the status?

Comment: task status is completed

Comment: @uma451 I apparently misunderstood that part of the request. Try the new version.

Comment: I have changed like this.It's not working

Comment: @uma451 Are you deleting the **task** or the **opportunity**?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51580/discussion-between-uma451-and-sfdcfox).

Comment: trying to delete the related list activity task from opportunity detail page

Comment: @uma451 Great. Glad I could help!